# Restrict the values of a string to a certain set in rust

Tags: string, rust

how do I restrict the vales of a string to a certain set in rust?

```js
// string literal union type with
// values of "admin", "owner", "user"
type Roles = "admin" | "owner" | "user";

// use the type "Roles" for the "role" variable
let role: Roles;

// assing a value other than "admin", "owner", "user"
role = "Hello World!"; // ❌ not allowed. Type '"Hello World!"' is not assignable to type 'Roles'

// assign a valid string value
role = "admin"; // ✅ allowed.
```

what is the equivalent in rust

Comment: An enum? Maybe with `strum`'s string conversion traits if you do need the string value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use an `enum` for your roles, and then use a serialization method (e.g. using `strum` or `serde`) to parse any string inputs and verify that they can be applied.

Here's an example using strum:

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;
use strum_macros::EnumString;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, EnumString)]
#[strum(ascii_case_insensitive)]
enum Role {
    Admin,
    Owner,
    User,
}

// tests
let admin = Role::from_str("admin").unwrap();
assert_eq!(Role::Admin, admin);
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer points to the right direction, but is a little short on details.

First install `strum` with the required features:

```bash
cargo add strum --features derive,strum_macros
```

Define your strings in an `enum` (note, with a custom `serialize` attribute you can enter any string format you want):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, EnumString, strum::Display)]
enum Role {
    #[strum(serialize = "admin")]
    Admin,

    #[strum(serialize = "Owner")]
    Owner,

    #[strum(serialize = "regular user")]
    User,

    #[strum(serialize = "GUEST")]
    Guest,
}
```

To covert from string to enum it relies on the FromStr trait (`use std::str::FromStr`):

```rust
let admin = Role::from_str("admin").unwrap();
assert_eq!(Role::Admin, admin);

let owner = Role::from_str("Owner").unwrap();
assert_eq!(Role::Owner, owner);

let user = Role::from_str("regular user").unwrap();
assert_eq!(Role::User, user);

let guest = Role::from_str("GUEST").unwrap();
assert_eq!(Role::Guest, guest);
```

To convert from enum to string (`strum::Display`):

```rust
let admin_str = Role::Admin.to_string();
assert_eq!("admin", admin_str);

let owner_str = Role::Owner.to_string();
assert_eq!("Owner", owner_str);

let user_str = Role::User.to_string();
assert_eq!("regular user", user_str);

let guest_str = Role::Guest.to_string();
assert_eq!("GUEST", guest_str);
```